# Monitoring number of request going through a port in linux servers

Tags: server, devops, monitoring, grafana

Im trying to set up a monitoring service to get the results of request going through a specific port. What i did was `netstat -anp | grep :8000 | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l` in the command line. however i would like to display the results on a dashboard similar to grafana but i cant seem to find any solutions online in doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grafana support lot of data sources https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/ and there are lot of agents to collect data as well. In our company we use InfluxDB and telegraf (https://docs.influxdata.com/telegraf/v1.17/introduction/installation/) as agent